# Problem setting up some critical paths when I run Wildfly 20 as a service

Tags: service, wildfly, classpath

I have a problem setting up some critical paths when I run Wildfly 20 as a service.

When I install (in "VM1") Wildfly in /home/myuser/ instead of /opt and NOT as a service and run it with the following, I am able to use the Admin console's "Test Connection" to connect to a Sybase SQL Anywhere database using the sajdbc4 driver.

```
cd ~/wildfly-20.0.1.Final/bin
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/myuser/wildfly-20.0.1.Final/modules/system/layers/base/com/sybase/main
export CLASSPATH=.:/home/myuser/wildfly-20.0.1.Final/modules/system/layers/base/com/sybase/main/sajdbc4.jar
./standalone.sh
```

LD_LIBRARY_PATH sets the path to the driver support files.

On the other hand, when I install Wildfly (in "VM2") exactly the same way as before except for installing into /opt and the extra steps to run Wildfly as a service as below, the Admin console's "Test Connection" fails with:

```
cd ~/wildfly-20.0.1.Final/bin
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/wildfly-20.0.1.Final/modules/system/layers/base/com/sybase/main
export CLASSPATH=.:/opt/wildfly-20.0.1.Final/modules/system/layers/base/com/sybase/main/sajdbc4.jar
sudo systemctl start wildfly

2020-08-28 13:13:41,341 INFO [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0183:
Service status report WFLYCTL0184: New missing/unsatisfied dependencies: service jboss.jdbc-driver.sajdbc4_jar (missing) dependents: [service jboss.driver-demander.java:jboss/datasources/TestDB, service org.wildfly.data-source.TestDB]
```

I can run a simple Java test app on the "VM02" system that connects and dumps a database table with:

```
cd $HOME/Desktop
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/wildfly-20.0.1.Final/modules/system/layers/base/com/sybase/main
export CLASSPATH=.:/opt/wildfly-20.0.1.Final/modules/system/layers/base/com/sybase/main/sajdbc4.jar
java sajdbc4DriverTest.java
```

This suggest ti me that all of the driver files are present at and the LD_LIBRARY_PATH location. Note that the launch of Wildlfly as a service uses the same paths.

Can anyone explain why Wildfly is ignoring the two paths I set prior to starting the service?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Service environment variables are not set this way.  And even if they were, the use of `sudo` changes to a new user with new environment variables.

Instead, if you installed Wildfly as documented in `wildfly-20.0.1.Final/docs/contrib/scripts/systemd`, add your environment variables in `/etc/wildfly/wildfly.conf`.  Something more like:

```
# The configuration you want to run
WILDFLY_CONFIG=standalone.xml

# The mode you want to run
WILDFLY_MODE=standalone

# The address to bind to
WILDFLY_BIND=0.0.0.0

# Add Sybase native library dir
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/wildfly-20.0.1.Final/modules/system/layers/base/com/sybase/main
```

I don't feel that you need to set CLASSPATH but I don't think it'll hurt either.

Comment: Excellent stdunbar! That solves it. Thank you very much for all your help!